# Match a code string in some text

Tags: regex, pcre

I have some code strings that I need to extract some data from, but specific data at that.

The strings are always in the same format.

1. I need to extract the text at the beginning between the ( and ), so it would extract `List Options` here.
2. I need to extract the text near the end `@groups` here.

The string I need at the end will always start with `@`

```
(List Options((join ", ", @groups))
```

I have tried:

```
^\((\w+).*, (@\w+)\)\)$
```

But it only gives me the word `List`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work well for you.

```
^\(([^(]+)[^@]+([^)]+)\)+$
```

See [working demo](http://www.regex101.com/r/mT2kI5)

Regular expression:

```
^          the beginning of the string
\(         look and match '('
 (         group and capture to \1:
  [^(]+    any character except: '(' (1 or more times)
 )         end of \1
  [^@]+    any character except: '@' (1 or more times)
 (         group and capture to \2:
  [^)]+    any character except: ')' (1 or more times)
 )         end of \2
 \)+       ')' (1 or more times)
$          before an optional \n, and the end of the string
```

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
^\(([^\(]+?)\(.*?@([^\)]+?)\)
```

or if you need the @ sign also captured, just move it inside the 2nd capturing group

```
^\(([^\(]+?)\(.*?(@[^\)]+?)\)
```